# Sylius install crashes because "No identifier defined"

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, sylius

I'm trying to install Sylius 1.8 on ubuntu and I follow installation guide when I run `composer install` I get following error:

```
Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [KO]
 [KO]
Script cache:clear returned with error code 1
!!  
!!   // Clearing the cache for the prod environment with debug                      
!!   // false                                                                       
!!  
!!  
!!  In FileLoader.php line 180:
!!                                                                                 
!!    No identifier defined "Sylius\Bundle\ApiBundle\Command\RegisterShopUser". Y  
!!    ou should add #[\ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty(identifier: true)]  
!!    " on the property identifying the resource." in . (which is being imported   
!!    from "/srv/sylius/vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ApiBundle/Resource  
!!    s/config/routing.yml"). Make sure there is a loader supporting the "api_pla  
!!    tform" type.                                                                 
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  In IdentifiersExtractor.php line 65:
!!                                                                                 
!!    No identifier defined "Sylius\Bundle\ApiBundle\Command\RegisterShopUser". Y  
!!    ou should add #[\ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiProperty(identifier: true)]  
!!    " on the property identifying the resource."                                 
!!                                                                                 
!!  
!!  cache:clear [--no-warmup] [--no-optional-warmers] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
!!  
!!  
Script @auto-scripts was called via post-install-cmd
```

I have also used Sylius docker but the result was the same, it seems there is an issue with Api-Platform.

Comment: Please share more details. If this is a generic problem directly after installing a software, it would be better to post this in the issue tracker of that software

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sylius uses Api-Platform, and very recently version 2.6 of Api-Platform was released.

Since this release, all API resources —including custom DTOs— need to have an "identifier", [as other users are finding out](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3975).

There already [exists a PR to fix this to make Sylius compatible with Api-Platform 2.6.0](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/pull/12274).

If you are installing a brand new project, you could do the following to install Sylius from scratch:

```shell
composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard app_dir --no-install --no-scripts 
cd app_dir
composer require api-platform/core:2.5.9 --no-update 
composer install
```

If you have an existing project you need to fix before updating (even one you've installed following the instructions on the previous step), you should add this to the `conflict` key of your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "conflict":  {
        "api-platform/core": ">=2.6.0"
    }
}
```

Although you should monitor the development of Sylius to remove this line once is no longer needed.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"api-platform/core": ">=2.6.0"` for the conflict key? Since this thread is referenced from the github issue it would be nice if you can fix it in your answer :)

Comment: Thanks, multitasking gets the best of us. And me as well.

Answer (score -1):

> Sylius uses Api-Platform, and very recently version 2.6 of
> Api-Platform was released.
>
> Since this release, all API resources —including custom DTOs— need to
> have an "identifier", as other users are finding out.
>
> There already exists a PR to fix this to make Sylius compatible with
> Api-Platform 2.6.0.
>
> If you are installing a brand new project, you could do the following
> to install Sylius from scratch:
>
> composer create-project sylius/sylius-standard app_dir --no-install
> --no-scripts  cd app_dir composer require api-platform/core:2.5.9 --no-update  composer install If you have an existing project you need to fix before updating, you could add this to the conflict key of your
> composer.json:
>
> {
> "conflict":  {
> "api-platform": ">=2.6.0"
> } } Although you should monitor the development of Sylius to remove this line once is no longer needed.

I work for me, however there is an error on the conflict package for update

```
"conflict": {
    "symfony/form": "4.4.11|4.4.12",
    "api-platform/core": ">=2.6.0"
},
```